# HTTP Streaming with Apache, Perl, and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, perl, apache

I'm trying to prepare a proof of concept for a page that will take a file that a user chooses, process it, and return it, all the while reporting on the status of the process.  I thought the best solution for this may be HTTP streaming, however I can only get it working in Firefox (not Chrome or IE8.)

### load.js

```
$(function() {
        var xhr = $.ajax({
                url: '/nph-handleRequest.cgi'
                ,type: 'get'
        });

        collectPartial(xhr,'');
});

var collectPartial = function (xhr,lastContent) {
        alert(xhr.readyState);
        if (xhr.readyState == 3 && lastContent != xhr.responseText) {
                lastContent = xhr.responseText;
                alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
        if (xhr.readyState < 4) {
                setTimeout(function() {collectPartial(xhr,lastContent)}, 1000);
        }
}
```

### nph-handleRequest.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$|=1;
print "$ENV{SERVER_PROTOCOL} 206 Partial Content\n";
print "Server: $ENV{SERVER_SOFTWARE}\n";
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
for ($count = 1; $count < 5; $count++) {
        print time();
        print "\n";
        sleep(2);
}
```

In Firefox, the alert(xhr.readyState) keeps displaying a 3, as I would expect.  In Chrome, though? 1. In IE it's 2.  Neither allow me to access responseText either.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

### Edit 1

It's actually MiniServ, not Apache.  The server doesn't appear to be the issue though, as it works in one browser, and not another.

### Edit 2

After discovering CGI::Push, I tried using that, despite warnings that it doesn't work in IE.  Oddly, it DID work in IE8 (not perfectly), but still not in Chrome.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$|=1;
use CGI::Push qw(:standard);

do_push(-next_page=>\&display_time,-delay=>2);

sub display_time {
        my($q,$counter) = @_;
        return undef if $counter > 5;
        return time()," "x256, "\n";
}
```

Comment: `s/EVN/ENV/` in line 4 of nph-handleRequest.cgi

Comment: Good catch.  Unfortunately, it isn't the source of the problem.

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you running? My recent attempts at reading partial contents from xhr.responseText failed in the latest version of Firefox - I was unable to read any data until the request completed.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Xaxxon. There was a time where some websites tried doing "fake AJAX" by having the server print out progress characters every now and then so the browser would wait for the process to finish, but each browser has different timeout and buffering rules.

The best way to do it is to have AJAX requests from the javascript on the page poll the server every n seconds asking it if the job is done, and when it is, displaying the results.  This should be much more reliable, and you can even have the code give up with an error message if the server stops responding or the job takes too long.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you take a different approach.  When the user uploads the file, you create a job of some sort on the server side and redirect the user to a page with the status of the job (or do it via ajax).  Then, when the job is complete, present them with the processed file.

Trying to do this in a single HTTP step is asking for problems like the one you see with different browsers (and probably different web servers if you ever wanted to switch the one you're using) having different behaviors.